# Proof of L'Hospital's Rule on Zorich book: an unclear step.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The proof of L'Hospital's rule on Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, chapter 5.4, pag. 251, starts with:

*if $g'(x)\neq 0$ we conclude on the basis of Rolle's theorem that $g(x)$ is strictly monotonic on $(a,b)$.*

In the hypothesis we have only that $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function on $(a,b)$.

So my question: we don't know if $g'(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ or not. So, $g'(x)$ could jump from negative values to positive values without passing through $0$, in theory. Consequently I think that, to conclude that $g(x)$ is strictly monotonic on $(a,b)$ when $g'(x) \neq 0 \;\;\forall x \in (a,b)$, we have to say:

let's assume that $\exists x_1,x_2\in (a,b)$ such that $g'(x_1)>0$ and $g'(x_2)<0$; then for [Darboux property of derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) we would have that $g'(x)$ assumes all values between $g'(x_1)$ and $g'(x_2)$, and so even $0$, that is a contradiction for the hypothesis that $g'(x) \neq 0 \;\;\forall x \in (a,b)$. Consequently $g'(x)$ has a definite sign that is the same $\forall x \in (a,b)$ and so $g(x)$ is strictly monotonic.

Is it right?

Comment: By Darboux's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis), $g'([a,b])$ is an interval.

Comment: I know, and so? 
Are there mistakes in my proof? If no, how can we justify the (faster) Zorich conclusion based on Rolle theorem?

Comment: If an interval of $\mathbf{R}$ does not contain zero, it must be completely contained in the positive or else in the negative side. Does this require a proof?

Comment: No, in fact the proof was not this, but it used this. Anyway @Martin R replied me, it's ok. Thank you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The continuity of $g'$ or Darboux's theorem is not needed for this conclusion. If $g$ is *not* strictly monotonic on $(a, b)$ then there must be $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ such that
$$
 g(x_1) \le g(x_2) \ge g(x_3) 
$$
or
$$
 g(x_1) \ge g(x_2) \le g(x_3) 
$$
In either case, there is $c < d$ with $g(c) = g(d)$, and Rolle's theorem ensures that $g'$ has a zero in $(c, d)$.

Comment: Oh, right... Thank you @Martin R.